# jQuery .toggle() button only toggles every other element

Tags: jquery, toggle

My code generates different elements on the click of one button. One of the elements generated is buttons which I want to toggle on and off parts of the text generated. The jQuery .toggle() function works for the first element generated. It then only works for the latest element generated and every other one before that (say, with 5 elements generated, it will work on 5, 3, 1 but not 2 and 4). It seems to be an issue with the class, I think, because I can, from the web console in Firefox use the .toggle() command to manually remove it. I guess this would mean the button is not triggering. I am at a loss.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/JaLBR/1/
Here is the code:

```
recursionCounter = 0
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#compute").click(function(){

    //add the toggle data
    $("#buttons").append("<input type=button value=\"Toggle\" class=\"removeBtn\" id=\"recursion" + recursionCounter + "\">")
    //add the recursion counter to the div element
    $("#recursion" + recursionCounter).data("recurs", recursionCounter)

    //make a new section for toggling purposed
    $("#results").append("<o" + (recursionCounter) + ">")
    //This code write the results to screen
    $("o" + (recursionCounter)).append("<br><br> <b>Recursion " + (recursionCounter) + "</b>")
    $("o" + (recursionCounter)).append("<br> Symmetric")

//toggles the recursion info
$(".removeBtn").on("click", function() {
    var count = $(this).data("recurs")
    $("o" + count).toggle()   
})


recursionCounter = recursionCounter + 1
})

})
```

With the appropriate 's on the html, as seen in the fiddle.

I think it could be due to nesting the call of the click inside of another click? I tried moving it out of the "compute" click, but it wouldn't toggle at all then (maybe because of scope?) But, the problem only shows itself on toggling. If make .toggle() into .hide(), all the buttons work. If I do separate show/hide buttons, then it works fine. If I write an if..else statement that does the toggling behaviour (using .is(:visible)) it also does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't replace the event handlers. If you attach two event handlers:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    console.log('a');
});

$('#foo').click(function() {
    console.log('a');
});
```

And click on `#foo`, both of them will fire.

Each time you add a new element, *every* `.removeBtn` element gets *another* event handler that toggles the visibility of its respective element. When you end up clicking on the button, all of the event handlers fire one after another and the element toggles an even or odd number of times, depending on how many buttons you've added.

To fix it, remove that event handler out of your `.click()` callback and just attach it with event delegation:

```
$('#buttons').on("click", ".removeBtn", function () {
    var count = $(this).data("recurs");
    $("o" + count).toggle()
});
```

Event delegation attaches the event handler to `#buttons`, which then delegates the event to the element that was clicked. This will account for all elements that match your selector, even if they're added later on.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JaLBR/4/**

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of why it needs to have the delegation. It really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `.removeBtn` click event outside the `#compute` button click event :

```
recursionCounter = 0
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#compute").click(function () {

        $("#buttons").append("<input type=button value=\"Toggle\" class=\"removeBtn\" id=\"recursion" + recursionCounter + "\">")
        $("#recursion" + recursionCounter).data("recurs", recursionCounter)

        $("#results").append("<o" + (recursionCounter) + ">")
        //This code write the results to screen
        $("o" + (recursionCounter)).append("<br><br> <b>Recursion " + (recursionCounter) + "</b>")
        //the removeButton
        //$("o" + (recursionCounter)).append("<input type=button value=\"Remove\" class=\"removeBtn\" id=\"remove" + recursionCounter + "\">")

        $("o" + (recursionCounter)).append("<br> Symmetric")
        recursionCounter = recursionCounter + 1
    });

    //removes the recursion info
    $('#buttons').on('click', ".removeBtn", function () {
        var count = $(this).data("recurs")
        console.log(count)
        $("o" + count).toggle()
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JaLBR/3/)